# How can I make jQuery ajax calls produce a response in the browser console?

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-console

I'm caching a number a links in a database via a page crawler that makes ajax calls with jQuery. Before making an ajax call to a remote site, I make sure the link address has one of a list of domains or has one of two file extensions:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

...

var substrings = ['site1',
                  'site2',
                  'site3',
                  'site4'];
var length = substrings.length;
console.log(length);
$.each(the_links, function(i, el){
  var dl_link = this;
  if (dl_link.endsWith('.html') || dl_link.endsWith('.php') || dl_link.indexOf(substrings[length])!=-1) {
    j.get( 'https://example.com/insert.php', { title:post_title, link: dl_link } )
        .done(function( data ) {
          console.log('response:');
          afterInsert(data);
        });
  }
  length--;
  if(link_count == 0){
    console.log('inserted all links');
  }
});
```

When I run the script, my ajax calls run without issues and my records are created in the database, but nothing is returned to the browser console in the ajax callback:

[image: Browser terminal output]

How can I access the contents of my ajax response?

I also tried the following ajax call and I'm still not able to log the response in my console, even though it appears in the `Response` tab of the XHR entry in the console:

```
j.get(insert_script, { title: post_title,link: dl_link}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   console.log('response:'); 
   afterInsert(data);
});
```

Comment: What is the `j` in `j.get` exactly?  A different version of jQuery or something?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I have jQuery running in no-conflict mode because the page I'm caching is running on a remote host with a different version of jQuery. Thus I use the following `var j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Hmm, perhaps that version of jquery doesnt dig the `.done`, what happens if you try `$.get('https://djpanaflex.com/custom/cache/insert.php', { title: post_title,link: dl_link}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  console.log('response:');  afterInsert(data);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my ajax response wasn't being provided to the console because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). I was able to get around this using the [CORS Everywhere](https://github.com/spenibus/cors-everywhere-firefox-addon) add-on for Firefox